# dispatch action outside component in react-sweet-state

Tags: reactjs, redux

i know that in redux, we can dispatch an action outside of the component, just import store and use store.dispatch to dispatch an action.

i'm using react-sweet-state, and i want to call an action outside of the component. Since redux-sweet-state using hook, i can not do that.

```
import { createStore, createSubscriber, createHook } from 'react-sweet-state';
const Store = createStore({
  initialState: {
    count: 0,
  },
actions: {
  increment: () => ({ setState, getState }) => {
    setState({
      count: getState().count + 1,
    });
  },
 },
});

const useCounter = createHook(Store);
```

i want to call increment outside of the component. Can someone help to for this issue..thanks

Answer (score 1):

In order to do it you must import a `defaultRegistry` and then use a `getStore` on it.

In your example it would look more or like it like this:

**counter.store.ts**

```
import { createStore, createSubscriber, createHook } from 'react-sweet-state';
const Store = createStore({
  initialState: {
    count: 0,
  },
actions: {
  increment: () => ({ setState, getState }) => {
    setState({
      count: getState().count + 1,
    });
  },
 },
});

const useCounter = createHook(Store);

export {useCounter, Store}; // export store variable here
```

**some-fn.ts**

```
import { defaultRegistry } from 'react-sweet-state'; // import those
import { Store } from './counter.store.ts';

const StoreInstance = defaultRegistry.getStore(Store); // we get access to store instance

const someFunction = () => {
  StoreInstance.actions.increment(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

import your store then you can use its dispatch function

```
import { store } from '/path/to/createdStore';
    ​
    function testAction(text) {
      return {
        type: 'TEST_ACTION',
        text
      }
    }
    ​
    store.dispatch(testAction('StackOverflow'));
```

Comment: I thought it'd be simple as well but it seems that `react-sweet-state` implements a different [store interface](https://atlassian.github.io/react-sweet-state/#/api/store) than redux does. I did only do a light poking around in the source though.